# Granting access to a Google Cloud Storage bucket to a third-party

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I need a third-party to upload some files to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. What is the best (or easiest) way to give them access?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The first two methods require that the user have a valid `Google Account`. I am ignoring `Google Identity Platform` in this answer. If the user has a `Gmail Account`, then this means they also have a `Google Account`. The third method uses a Google Service Account.

**Method 1: Use the Google Cloud Storage Console:**

- Go to `Storage` -> `Browser`.
- Check the desired bucket. In the right side panel under `permissions`, click the `Add` button.
- Add the user's Google Account email address. Select `Storage Object Creator`.

The role granted is `roles/storage.objectCreator`. This role grants the user permissions to create objects in the bucket but the user cannot delete or overwrite objects.

[Link to Cloud Storage Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud_storage_roles)

**Method 2: Use the gsutl CLI:**

```
gsutil iam ch user:username@example.com:ObjectCreator gs://examplebucket
```

[Link to gcloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/iam)

Command to read the current bucket IAM policy:

```
gsutil iam get gs://examplebucket
```

**Method 3: Use a Google Service Account**

Create a Google Service Account in the Google Cloud Console

1. Go to `IAM & admin` -> `Service accounts`
2. Click `CREATE SERVICE ACCOUNT`
3. Enter a `Service account name` and `Service account description`
4. Click `CREATE`
5. In the next screen `Service account permissions`, select a role.
6. Select `Storage` -> `Storage Object Creator`
7. Click `CONTINUE`
8. Click `Create key`
9. Check the `JSON` radio button for the `Key type`
10. Save the json file to your local computer.

You now have `Google Service Account` credentials that can be setup with `gsutil`, `gcloud` and software programs.

[Setting up gcloud with Service Account Credentials](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-setting-up-gcloud-with-service-account-credentials/)

Answer (score 0):

The way you grant access to your third-party Customers to upload files to a Google Cloud Storage bucket would differ from one programming language to another. In PHP, you would write something like:

$options = ['gs_bucket_name' => $my_bucket];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload/handler', $options);

and get an upload URL as a result. You may find more detail on this solution in the "Allowing Users to Upload Files" online [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload).